# How do you display the code (not output) that .Net T4 generates?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, t4

We have a set of T4 templates we have just migrated forward to VS 2010 and they compile but are no longer working the same.

In order to see what is actually going on *under the hood* it would be useful to see the temporary cs files that T4 generates to produce the actual T4 conversion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you're now using Visual Studio 2010, you can also change the custom tool on the template from TextTemplatingFileGenerator to TextTemplatingFilePreprocessor temporarily.

This will spit out the underlying code directly into your project instead of the regular template output.

Comment: +1 +correct: That wins my vote for sheer convenience. It generates the .cs right where the .config was. Cool! Many thanks.

Comment: One word of warning to everyone using source control... changing the T4 tool causes the previous output file to be marked for deletion.

Comment: +1 Used this to compile `EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude` into an assembly containing the classes.

Answer (score 5):

If you set

```
<#@ template  debug="true"#>
```

then the generated code will be left in your temp directory. On my Windows 7 system, that's `C:\Users\John Saunders\AppData\Local\Temp`.

Comment: The client I am at is running Windows Server 2003 on all machines. Any idea where the files may go or what they are named so I can find them?

Comment: They have random names. Maybe look in C:\Temp or the value of the %TEMP% environment variable.

Comment: The %TEMP% was the right location. Your solution works a treat and I am now able to see what it is generating. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do exactly what you want, however I do know how to step through the t4 code in visual studio. You need to start a second instance of visual studio and attach it to the first instance using the Debug->Attach to process... (Attaching it to itself, weird, I know). This then allows you to put breakpoints in the T4 file in your second instance and it will stop and let you step through it and see what is going on.

Edit:

You need to be doing the t4 transform in visual studio instead of the command line tool for this to work. Put your .tt file in to your project and set the "Custom Tool" in its properties to "TextTemplatingFileGenerator". It will generate the files every time you tell the file to save, or when you right click and say "Run Custom Tool" on the file. See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd820620.aspx) for more info.

I also recommend getting the [tangible T4 editor](http://t4-editor.tangible-engineering.com/T4-Editor-Visual-T4-Editing.html) the free version adds code highlighting and  intellisense to about 90% of the use cases I needed for it (it only adds it for functions in Core.dll for the .NET framework). the pay version will add intellisense to all attached assemblies.

Edit2: If you REALLY want the temporary cs files it uses you can see what cs files from the temporary folder are loaded in the debugger (i don't remember exactly where).

Comment: I removed the stuff about the command line options as misleading (we are running in Dev Studio). The breakpoint from a second copy of Dev Studio did not work though. After attaching to VS-2010-copy-1, on any tt file in VS-2010-copy-2 a breakpoint shows "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document". Can you provide more information?

Comment: I previously have tried, and had to unload, the tangible T4 editor as it conflicted with my other add-ins. Basic text search options were no longer available.

Comment: @HiTech Magic, I will look in to my setup, but it may be a few hours before I have time. check back tonight.